# How to deserialize a json in .net core 3.0

Tags: json, .net-core, json.net, blazor

I have been facing some trouble to deserialize a json using .Net Core 3.0 Blazor app.

The Framework i am using .Net Core 3.0 Blazor with Visual Studio Preview 2019

```
{
    "cols": [
        "ID",
        "LastName",
        "Firstname",
        "middlename",
        "Suffix",
        "Title"

    ],
    "rows": [
        [
            "90",
            "Dada",
            "Mama",
            "",
            "",
            ""

        ]
    ]
}
```

Expected result:
i want to load this json dynamically as a table in the web form using blazor. I don't mind to use any UI framwork for this like devexpress or telerik.

id             LastNmae Firstname middlename Suffix Title

90        Dada   Mama

[Expected Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JcVDt.jpg)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### Steps accomplish on Blazor:

1.- Add `Newtonsoft` to your Blazor project (for Blazor client side wasm it is also possible because Newtonsoft is netstandard):

```
dotnet add package Newtonsoft.Json
```

2.- Referencing library, deserializing and iterating over deserialized objects:

```
@page "/counter"

@using Newtonsoft.Json

<table >
    <tr>
        @foreach (var c in dyn.cols)
        {
            <td style="border: 1px solid black;">@c.Value</td>    
        }
    </tr>
    @foreach (var r in dyn.rows)
    {
        <tr>
            @foreach (var d in r)
            {
                <td style="border: 1px solid black;">@d.Value</td>    
            }
        </tr>
    }
</table>

@code {
    dynamic dyn;
    string json_str = @" your json ";

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
          dyn = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json_str);
    }
}
```

#### Result:

[image]

#### Other info:

The whole json of the sample:

```
@code {
    dynamic dyn;
    string json_str = @"
        {
            ""cols"": [
                ""ID"",
                ""LastName"",
                ""Firstname"",
                ""middlename"",
                ""Suffix"",
                ""Title""

            ],
            ""rows"": [
                [
                    ""90"",
                    ""Dada"",
                    ""Mama"",
                    """",
                    """",
                    """"
                ],
                [
                    ""91"",
                    ""Dada1"",
                    ""Mama1"",
                    """",
                    """",
                    """"
                ],
            ]
        }
    ";
```

**Edited:**

Disclaimer: at this time, you can also use [System.Text.Json](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/try-the-new-system-text-json-apis/)

Comment: Thanks and it is working now. Can you please tell me how can i point to a json file like string json_str = @"sample-data/User.json"; instead of write the json inside string

Comment: Post another post for your new question. It's free 

Comment: Disclaimer: at this time, you can also use [System.Text.Json](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/try-the-new-system-text-json-apis/)