# Blazor - deserialise with constructor injection

Tags: blazor, blazor-client-side

I have a blazor client application, that is fetching a model from the server using `HttpClient`.

I have no problem deserialising a POCO, but now I'd like to deserialise a model object that should have a dependency (registered on the client side) injected at the point it is constructed during the deserialisation process. Is this possible using the `System.Text.Json` serialiser on the client?

Comment: Yes, it is. Actually it's already a blazor client-side dependency

Comment: Also you can use NewtonSoft: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57594192/842935